# TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I want to test my function which checks if my variable is an instance of a type I am using and does something.
I do the check like this and it works as expected.

```
myCheckingFunction = () => {
 if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
 ...
 }
}
```

But when I want to test this code by calling the function in my test (I am testing with jest), then it throws the typeError.

Why is this happening and how can I get pass this?

**EDIT:**
After some further investigation I realized, that this wont work by just calling the function in the test and assuming everything should work fine. It's linked to the type I am checking at instanceof 'H.map.Marker' in `myCheckingFunction`.

My project setup at this point is not the best, but I have to deal with that. This is what I have:

```
class MockEventTarget {}
(global as any).H = {
  map: {
    Marker: MockEventTarget,
  },
};

// this is how I call my test for myCheckingFunction
testMyCheckingFunction({target: new MockEventTarget()});
```

Due to the fact that I cant just import the H.map.Marker in my test, I am creating a dummy class. Then creating a global variable where I tell my test-setup to assume that the H.map.Marker is a class.

With this setup I don't get the error-message from above anymore because my test can actually call a dummy-constructor now.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable

Comment: What is H.map.Marker?

Comment: It is a type of an object.

Comment: Please provide the definition of it and how you import it (if you do) in your question. Your question lacks enough information for anyone to help you right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code this should work:

```
myCheckingFunction = (e) => {
 if (e.target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
 ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Still the same. But why should this work anyway? Its about the typing my test fails. Not because of the functionality - functionality is working well, just the test not.